# Hue like texture with glow, outer and inner with cycles and node editor

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, node-editor, color

How it is possible to create texture as on the provided image in Cycles and node editor ?

So it has this nice HUE glow inside around edges, almost x-ray-ish felling

[image]

and second nice glow outside which takes the color of the object in cycles

[image]

Tried different approaches and also tried to fake it in Compositing but nothing really worked.

Thank you for directing me to right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you use a *Fresnel* node to emit color from the edges.  If you have picked the colors you want, use a *Mix Shader* to control the emission strength by the *Factor* input.

[image]

Notice in this example I've used no shader in the first input, because we want the color to come back pure black in the unmapped areas.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer .... its something that I was looking for. One last question, how to achieve the gloving effect ? tried to use glow in Compositing but with no luck

Comment: Glare node set to fog glow should do it